# the maximum likelihood estimator of $p?$

Tags: probability, statistics

$X$ is a single observation from Binomial $(1, p)$ population, where $p \in [1/5, 4/5]$ is unknown. If the observed value of $X$ is zero, then the maximum likelihood estimator of $p?$

I am stuck with this problem, please help.

Comment: Have you constructed the likelihood function $L(p)$?

Answer (score 1):

The pmf of a bernoulli random variable is 
$$
P(X=x)=p^x(1-p)^{1-x}; \quad (x=0,1)\tag{1}\label{1}
$$
Given an observation $x=0$, the Likelihood function is 
$$
L(p)=1-p
$$
by substituting $x=0$ into $\eqref{1}$. If $p\in[1/5, 4/5]$ what value of $p$ maximizes $L(p)$.

Comment: Yes, I got it $p=1/5$, but why u write $x=0, 1$ in (1)